# Please show me the basic pattern for Parse Promises

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around Parse Promises.
I'm trying to save an object that could have an image. I can save the post, but the image is never saved.

Here's my attempt at getting the promises to work.

```
var savePromise = new Parse.Promise.as();

  if(request.params.imageData){ // if there is image data, save the image

    var image = new Parse.File(fileName, request.params.imageData);

   savePromise = image.save().then(function() {
    groupPost.set(constants.kBPGroupImageKey, image);
    });
 }

else{// no saved image, resolve the promise and save
    return savePromise;   
}
    groupPost.save().then(function(groupPost){
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(request.params.imageData){
    //create the image
    var image = new Parse.File(fileName, request.params.imageData);

    image.save()
       .then(function(savedImage) {
           //returns your savedImage if you want to use it

           groupPost.set(constants.kBPGroupImageKey, image);

           // return the promise to chain them using 'then'
           return groupPost.save(); })
       .then(function(savedGroupPost) {
           //grouppost is saved
        }, function(error) {
           // errors will bubble up here
    });
 }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, this will save the image, but if there is no image, it doesn't save correctly.

Comment: Could you just save the post in an else block if request does not contain an image?

Comment: I'm need to access the returned object and save the pointer to another object.

Comment: If there is no 'image' then how can a pointer be created to it? Perhaps this question has strayed from the original promise patterns question.